# Center input with span in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have View with some inputs with spans.

Here is code

```
div  class="inner-right2-calendar" style="text-align: center">
<div class="input-group date" style="display: inline-block;"  id="picker">
    <input id="startAppointment" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Start Appointment"/>
        <span style="width: 20px; height: 33px;" class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
   </div>
<div class="input-group date" style="padding-left: 130px; margin-top: 20px;" id="picker2">
    <input id="endAppointment" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter End Appointment" />
    <span style="width: 20px; height: 33px;" class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here is css of `inner-right2-calendar`

```
.inner-right2-calendar {
background: #fafafa;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
margin-top: 20px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
height: 30%;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
```

}

```
.input-group {
```

position: relative;

border-collapse: separate;
}

I need to center `class="input-group date"` in parent div

I try to do it with `text-align` for parent div and `display: inline-block;` for children.

But now I see this

[image]

How I can center it?

Comment: provide a link or create a fiddle pls

Comment: you want the buttons to be in the center?

Comment: input and span fields@hunzaboy

Comment: single line or multiple lines?

Comment: single line @hunzaboy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove all inline styles and just add `form-inline` and `text-center` to parent.** That's it.

Note: Please try to use as much bootstrap as you can and avoid inline styling to get desired results. :)

```
<div class="inner-right2-calendar form-inline text-center">
  <div class="input-group date" id="picker">
    <input id="startAppointment" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Start Appointment" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group date" id="picker2">
    <input id="endAppointment" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter End Appointment" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `.input-group.date` has a fixed width. In that case you can do:

```
.input-group.date
{
  width: 200px; /* whatever the fixed width is */
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/6hhp2v0w/1/
Don't look at the colors ;) Just give the `.input-group.date` a fixed width and `margin: 0px auto`. Should be all there is to it!

Answer (score 0):

Here the Solution

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div  class="inner-right2-calendar" style="text-align: center">  
<div class="input-group date" style="padding-left: 130px; margin-top: 20px;" id="picker2">
    <input id="endAppointment" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Start Appointment" />
    <span style="width: 20px; height: 33px;" class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="input-group date" style="padding-left: 130px; margin-top: 20px;" id="picker2">
    <input id="endAppointment" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter End Appointment" />
    <span style="width: 20px; height: 33px;" class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Padding-left? you mean this?